# Azure CLI: Accept SendGrid's legal terms

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-marketplace

We are trying to automate deployment of our custom solution using Azure Cli and it is mainly successful except for one annoying issue: we cannot find the way to accept legal terms for SendGrid via Azure Cli.

We have no issues doing it via PowerShell:

```
Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher "Sendgrid" -Product "sendgrid_azure" -Name "free" | Set-AzMarketplaceTerms -Accept
```

But how do we do the same using Azure Cli? Can someone, please help with it? Is it even possible? The reason we want to use Azure CLI is because 99% of the deployment script is using it. We don't want to use PowerShell for the last 1% becase the user needs to authenticate to Azure PowerShell Module one more time unceccessarily.

This is what SendGrid Product looks like when we run this command:

```
Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher "Sendgrid" -Product "sendgrid_azure" -Name "free"
```

Result (which is great, we want to see this):

> Publisher         : Sendgrid Product           : sendgrid_azure Plan
>   : free LicenseTextLink   :
>   https://storelegalterms.blob.core.windows.net/legalterms/3E5ED_legalterms_SENDGRID%253a24SENDGRID%253a5FAZURE%253a24FREE%253a24YETL367I3WKHD54DOKWY3WW3VV6IKDF32UCLUQA6JEV
>                       4GAZY2JLEYCDJI64NPQ2OLUJMS5R2JHZOXC663I73AX45FCBR5CFAYEKUO2Y.txt
>   PrivacyPolicyLink : http://sendgrid.com/privacy Signature         :
>   BZU4R7BG2MVWROB7QPWQ6OXCPG7ZYPLNRJXXQC2TU4MLWHMXXQCRQ2Y7BKWL4CIVYULXIGPNUSIISNDP6SVWZ7DFZ3EEX7NYJKOBVKY
>   Accepted          : True Signdate          : 2019-04-08 1:00:06 AM

I have tried these **Azure Cli** commands:

```
az vm image list --all --publisher sendgrid --offer sendgrid_azure --sku free --query '[].urn'
az vm image list --all --publisher Sendgrid --offer sendgrid_azure --sku free --query '[].urn'
az vm image list --all --publisher SendGrid --offer sendgrid_azure --sku free --query '[].urn'
```

But this is what they return:

> []

When I try some other publishers,

```
az vm image list --all --publisher cisco --offer cisco-csr-1000v --sku 16_6 --query '[].urn'
```

then I see some items returned:

> [   {
>       "offer": "cisco-csr-1000v",
>       "publisher": "cisco",
>       "sku": "16_6",
>       "urn": "cisco:cisco-csr-1000v:16_6:16.6.120170804",
>       "version": "16.6.120170804"   },   {
>       "offer": "cisco-csr-1000v",
>       "publisher": "cisco",
>       "sku": "16_6",
>       "urn": "cisco:cisco-csr-1000v:16_6:16.6.220171219",
>       "version": "16.6.220171219"   } ]

Any help will be greatly appreciated! How do we accept legal terms uzing Azure CLI?

Comment: The two commands call the different apis, not know the reason. If you use a non-interactive login to use the powershell, will you accept to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

az vm image accept-terms --publisher sendgrid --offer sendgrid_azure --plan free

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accept the TnCs for SendGrid via below commands.

`Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher "Sendgrid" -Product "sendgrid_azure" -Name "free" | Set-AzMarketplaceTerms -Accept`

Comment: great approach! thank you Adee! On my end I never figured it out and had to manually accept the license. But I will use your approach from now on.

Comment: No worries Denis, thanks a lot for the acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0):

The probable Azure CLI equivalent commands are  [az vm image list-publishers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/image?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-image-list-publishers) and [az vm image accept-terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/image?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-image-accept-terms)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi KrishnaG. Thank you for your reply, but if you look at my question you will see that I've used these already. The problem is that `az vm image list --all --publisher sendgrid` does not return anything.